# How to click on Div and Redirect on others page particular Div

Tags: html, redirect, anchor

I want to point the div on other page particular  Div  i try both 
ways

```
   <div class="B_and_A" onClick="document.location='/discovers/page2#who_me';">

and 

<a href='/discovers/page2#who_me'
<div class="B_and_A">
    </div>
</a>
```

But **its just redirect on other page but on on particular Div of others Page**
Actually Its Give me this On **Magento**

**ERROR::**

**jquery.js:3123 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin  from accessing a cross-origin frame.**

Comment: You seem to be lacking the extension of the file

Comment: @Swellar Please Elaborate  **lacking the extension**

Comment: Did you put a <a name="who_me"> (EDIT : sorry: <a id="who_me">) on the top of the div of the second page?

Comment: Either `.html` or `.php` in `page2`

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar OP should use `id` attribute and not the `name` attribute

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar I <a id="who_me"> rather then  <a name="who_me">

Comment: Yes <a id="who_me">

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar
Page 2: <div id="woke_up" class="woke-up">

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar i update error Details After seen Console Log 
It will Surely helps you .

Answer (score 0):

your div lacks an anchor.

page1

```
<a href='/discovers/page2#who_me'></a>
```

page2

```
<div id="who_me" class="B_and_A">
</div>
```